# update database record in while loop php

Tags: php, postgresql, while-loop

I am trying to develop a simple page in php to update attendance days.I have set the query to display the records from db and added a check box with data displayed from db.I want to update the specific record of db on which check box is checked.i want to update the the attendance column with 1 to existing value.for this i just tried written code to display the data from db and added a check box but dnt know to update the record where check box is checked on submit button.here is my initial code.any one help

```
<?php
require_once("../db/db_connect.php");
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
$sql = "SELECT cv_id, cd_id, cv_fomfeeback FROM candidateverification;";
$res = pg_query($sql) or die ($sql);
    // output data of each row
    while($row = pg_fetch_row($res)){
        echo "cd id: " . $row[0]. "  cv id: " . $row[1]. "  atn: " . $row[2]. "<input type='checkbox' value='1'/> <br>";
    }
 ?>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<body>    
    <input type="button" action="update" value="Submit"/>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to update cv_fomfeeback column with +1 if check box is checked.

Comment: For starters to have a working from you need a <form> tag. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Also you should name the checkbox. Here is a very good tutorial how they work in php: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: yes its good idea.but please give some idea to update the db record if checkbox is checked when i press submit button

Comment: Well build a valid html form based on the resources I gave you and when you post the form with the submit button you will get the data you need to work with in the $_POST array. I will not write code for you, I have only time to comment with some resource.

Comment: i am new to php.its my ist page ever in php.i can't follow the hints...

Comment: First you change your code so it outputs a valid html form. If it is a valid form when you press submit it will send the checkboxes data in the $_POST array. Read this tutorial about this: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html

Answer (score 0):

First you need to name your checkbox. You must do this in a way, so that you get all the checkboxes (-> array) and know the row id of the checkes boxes (-> associative array).

Your checkbox could look like this:

```
echo "<input type=\"checkbox" name=\"boxes[{$row[0]}]\" value=\"1\">";
```

On the page that is called after submit has been done (see the comment of @TheNAkos) you will find all checked boxes in the associative array accessible via

```
$_POST["boxes"]
```

From there you need to loop through the array and update the rows accordingly.

I will not post a complete example, but those hints should help you find the solution by yourself.